# Isomorphism onto nonzero reals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

As part of a problem, I must show the following:

Prove that there exists an isomorphism such that $$(\{1,-1\},\cdot)\times((0,\infty),\cdot)\simeq(\mathbb{R}-\{0\},\cdot).$$ How would one actually define a map to show this? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: hint each number has a unique sign and magnitude

Comment: $(a,b) \mapsto ab$ is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Crostul How exactly would you show that this mapping is well-defined and onto?

Comment: @Crostul Nevermind about well-defined; I just figured that out. But can I just assume that it is onto because every element in $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ can be expressed as the image of an element in the domain?

Comment: @A.S.Hopkins That's the general meaning of "onto", so yes.